# ¿Como redireccionar correctamente en React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Sucede que estoy trabajando en una aplicación web, y estoy intentando hacer el login, que posee una api externa, la comunicación con la api esta funcionando perfectamente, sin embargo no he podido redireccionar cuando reciba el token.

```
import { URL } from 'constants/ActionTypes'

export function Login(userData) {

fetch(`${URL}/auth/login`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(userData),
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLhttpRequest'
    },
    mode: 'cors'
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
    .then(result => {
        let res = result;
        if(res.access_token){
            sessionStorage.setItem('token', res.access_token)
            console.log('Bien')
        }
        else{
            console.log("try again")
        }
 })
}
```

Esa es la función de llamado a la api, y las respuestas son positivas, intente hacerlo con redict, sin embargo esto no funciono, cuales son otras opciones?

Comment: ¿Has probado con `window.location.href = '/destino'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal seria que tengas en un stack de navegacion y en el tengas un `<AuthStack>` y `<HomeStack>` donde tengas todas las pantallas correspondiente al login y home separadas y luego hagas render en una pantalla principal dependiendo el dato que recibas, ene ste caso seria al momento que tengas `access_token`